# Using "by" with helper function error in r

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I'm trying to apply a helper function to a data frame by factor.
My function works (I know because I have already used it a lot and it also works with the complete data frame) and the spelling is correct.
However, when I want to apply I get an error:

```
pru<-by(  data = cs_us[,3:length(cs_us)],
+           INDICES = cs_us$ensayo,
+           FUN =desplazar(cs_us$tiempo,cs_us[,3:length(cs_us)-1])
+ )
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

If I try to find it, it is in the Global Environment

```
getAnywhere(desplazar)
A single object matching ‘desplazar’ was found
It was found in the following places
  .GlobalEnv
with value

function(tiempo,dataframe){
  matriz = as.matrix(dataframe)
  matriz_dif = abs(diff(matriz )) # derivar
  matriz_dif_inv = diffinv(matriz_dif) # integrar
  return(data.frame(cbind(tiempo, matriz_dif_inv )))
}
```

Here's a piece of my data (just the critical part for you to have the 2 factor levels)

```
dput(cs_us[120:140,])
structure(list(estado = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), tiempo = c(624, 
624.2, 624.4, 624.6, 624.8, 625, 625.2, 625.4, 625.6, 625.8, 
626, 626.2, 626.4, 626.6, 626.8, 627, 3120.2, 3120.4, 3120.6, 
3120.8, 3121), UT2x45.1 = c(13666L, 13665L, 13664L, 13662L, 13661L, 
13655L, 13651L, 13648L, 13647L, 13643L, 13642L, 13640L, 13638L, 
13637L, 13637L, 13636L, 11115L, 11115L, 11115L, 11115L, 11115L
), UT2x45.2 = c(15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 
15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 15357L, 
15357L, 15357L, 15087L, 15087L, 15087L, 15087L, 15087L), TR2x45.1 = c(15761L, 
15755L, 15742L, 15729L, 15727L, 15726L, 15724L, 15722L, 15720L, 
15716L, 15717L, 15715L, 15711L, 15708L, 15706L, 15704L, 15628L, 
15628L, 15628L, 15628L, 15628L), TR2x45.2 = c(15381L, 15363L, 
15342L, 15324L, 15320L, 15314L, 15308L, 15298L, 15296L, 15294L, 
15293L, 15293L, 15293L, 15294L, 15294L, 15294L, 14238L, 14238L, 
14238L, 14238L, 14238L), UT2x45.3 = c(15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 
15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 
15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15649L, 15532L, 15532L, 15532L, 
15532L, 15532L), UT2x45.4 = c(16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 
16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 
16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16038L, 16136L, 16136L, 16136L, 16136L, 
16136L), TR2x45.3 = c(15662L, 15658L, 15658L, 15657L, 15657L, 
15653L, 15649L, 15648L, 15647L, 15646L, 15645L, 15644L, 15644L, 
15637L, 15633L, 15632L, 16123L, 16123L, 16123L, 16123L, 16123L
), TR2x45.4 = c(15780L, 15761L, 15743L, 15732L, 15729L, 15726L, 
15720L, 15715L, 15713L, 15712L, 15709L, 15705L, 15704L, 15703L, 
15702L, 15702L, 15233L, 15233L, 15232L, 15233L, 15233L), TR2x45.5 = c(16072L, 
16075L, 16077L, 16078L, 16078L, 16080L, 16082L, 16083L, 16084L, 
16086L, 16087L, 16088L, 16088L, 16089L, 16091L, 16093L, 16198L, 
16198L, 16198L, 16198L, 16198L), TR2x45.6 = c(16100L, 16087L, 
16072L, 16062L, 16055L, 16049L, 16044L, 16040L, 16035L, 16030L, 
16024L, 16025L, 16026L, 16024L, 16022L, 16022L, 16306L, 16306L, 
16306L, 16306L, 16306L), UT2x45.5 = c(15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 
15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 
15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 15642L, 16140L, 16140L, 16140L, 
16140L, 16140L), UT2x45.6 = c(16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 
16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 
16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16546L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 
16428L), TR2x45.7 = c(19030L, 19035L, 19033L, 19029L, 19028L, 
19027L, 19026L, 19025L, 19023L, 19022L, 19022L, 19022L, 19022L, 
19022L, 19022L, 19022L, 20119L, 20119L, 20118L, 20119L, 20120L
), TR2x45.8 = c(20874L, 20883L, 20886L, 20887L, 20889L, 20891L, 
20896L, 20898L, 20899L, 20901L, 20903L, 20907L, 20912L, 20916L, 
20920L, 20923L, 29200L, 29200L, 29200L, 29200L, 29200L), UT2x45.7 = c(15731L, 
15730L, 15729L, 15729L, 15726L, 15724L, 15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 
15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 15722L, 15567L, 
15567L, 15567L, 15567L, 15567L), UT2x45.8 = c(14584L, 14584L, 
14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 
14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14584L, 14080L, 14080L, 
14080L, 14080L, 14082L), UT2x45.9 = c(15900L, 15900L, 15901L, 
15902L, 15902L, 15908L, 15911L, 15911L, 15912L, 15913L, 15913L, 
15913L, 15913L, 15913L, 15913L, 15913L, 15941L, 15941L, 15941L, 
15941L, 15941L), UT2x45.10 = c(14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 
14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 
14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 14906L, 13890L, 13890L, 13890L, 13890L, 
13890L), TR2x45.9 = c(16072L, 16072L, 16072L, 16072L, 16072L, 
16072L, 16072L, 16072L, 16072L, 16071L, 16071L, 16071L, 16071L, 
16071L, 16071L, 16071L, 16240L, 16240L, 16240L, 16240L, 16240L
), TR2x45.10 = c(13995L, 13981L, 13948L, 13929L, 13916L, 13906L, 
13900L, 13893L, 13881L, 13870L, 13863L, 13854L, 13846L, 13839L, 
13834L, 13826L, 3363L, 3363L, 3363L, 3363L, 3363L), UT2x45.11 = c(16673L, 
16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 
16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 16673L, 17391L, 
17391L, 17391L, 17391L, 17391L), UT2x45.12 = c(16197L, 16194L, 
16194L, 16194L, 16192L, 16191L, 16191L, 16190L, 16188L, 16185L, 
16185L, 16184L, 16184L, 16184L, 16183L, 16182L, 16493L, 16493L, 
16493L, 16493L, 16493L), TR2x45.11 = c(15590L, 15588L, 15587L, 
15587L, 15585L, 15585L, 15585L, 15585L, 15584L, 15584L, 15584L, 
15584L, 15590L, 15590L, 15590L, 15589L, 15464L, 15464L, 15464L, 
15464L, 15464L), TR2x45.12 = c(13279L, 13255L, 13221L, 13190L, 
13182L, 13177L, 13174L, 13166L, 13159L, 13157L, 13154L, 13147L, 
13141L, 13138L, 13138L, 13135L, 8705L, 8705L, 8705L, 8705L, 8705L
), TR2x45.13 = c(14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 
14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14342L, 14343L, 14342L, 
14341L, 14341L, 13276L, 13276L, 13276L, 13276L, 13276L), TR2x45.14 = c(17163L, 
17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 
17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17163L, 17888L, 
17888L, 17888L, 17888L, 17888L), UT2x45.13 = c(15769L, 15769L, 
15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 
15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15769L, 15702L, 15702L, 
15702L, 15702L, 15702L), UT2x45.14 = c(18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 
18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 
18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 18606L, 22677L, 22677L, 22677L, 
22677L, 22677L), TR2x45.15 = c(15986L, 15989L, 15990L, 15990L, 
15990L, 15990L, 15990L, 15990L, 15989L, 15988L, 15988L, 15988L, 
15988L, 15988L, 15988L, 15988L, 15998L, 15998L, 15998L, 15998L, 
15998L), TR2x45.16 = c(16328L, 16347L, 16362L, 16367L, 16366L, 
16365L, 16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 
16366L, 16366L, 16366L, 17946L, 17946L, 17946L, 17946L, 17946L
), UT2x45.15 = c(15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 
15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 15768L, 
15768L, 15768L, 16168L, 16168L, 16168L, 16168L, 16168L), UT2x45.16 = c(16040L, 
16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 
16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16040L, 16037L, 
16037L, 16037L, 16037L, 16037L), UT2x45.17 = c(15749L, 15749L, 
15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 
15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15749L, 15677L, 15677L, 
15677L, 15677L, 15677L), UT2x45.18 = c(18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 
18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 
18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 18179L, 16152L, 16152L, 16152L, 
16152L, 16152L), TR2x45.17 = c(16423L, 16426L, 16427L, 16428L, 
16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 
16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 16428L, 17110L, 17110L, 17110L, 17110L, 
17110L), TR2x45.18 = c(13624L, 13613L, 13586L, 13573L, 13566L, 
13558L, 13554L, 13548L, 13546L, 13543L, 13540L, 13538L, 13533L, 
13531L, 13527L, 13526L, 12369L, 12369L, 12369L, 12369L, 12369L
), UT2x45.19 = c(8263L, 8259L, 8257L, 8255L, 8254L, 8253L, 8252L, 
8250L, 8246L, 8239L, 8235L, 8235L, 8234L, 8232L, 8229L, 8226L, 
1579L, 1579L, 1579L, 1579L, 1579L), UT2x45.20 = c(17469L, 17469L, 
17470L, 17471L, 17473L, 17475L, 17475L, 17475L, 17475L, 17476L, 
17477L, 17479L, 17481L, 17482L, 17482L, 17483L, 19822L, 19822L, 
19823L, 19823L, 19824L), TR2x45.19 = c(15723L, 15709L, 15671L, 
15634L, 15617L, 15598L, 15582L, 15568L, 15557L, 15547L, 15537L, 
15526L, 15517L, 15506L, 15501L, 15496L, 14338L, 14338L, 14338L, 
14338L, 14338L), TR2x45.20 = c(15818L, 15822L, 15825L, 15829L, 
15833L, 15837L, 15838L, 15839L, 15840L, 15841L, 15843L, 15845L, 
15847L, 15849L, 15851L, 15854L, 14945L, 14945L, 14945L, 14945L, 
14945L), ensayo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E1", 
"E2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("estado", "tiempo", "UT2x45.1", 
"UT2x45.2", "TR2x45.1", "TR2x45.2", "UT2x45.3", "UT2x45.4", "TR2x45.3", 
"TR2x45.4", "TR2x45.5", "TR2x45.6", "UT2x45.5", "UT2x45.6", "TR2x45.7", 
"TR2x45.8", "UT2x45.7", "UT2x45.8", "UT2x45.9", "UT2x45.10", 
"TR2x45.9", "TR2x45.10", "UT2x45.11", "UT2x45.12", "TR2x45.11", 
"TR2x45.12", "TR2x45.13", "TR2x45.14", "UT2x45.13", "UT2x45.14", 
"TR2x45.15", "TR2x45.16", "UT2x45.15", "UT2x45.16", "UT2x45.17", 
"UT2x45.18", "TR2x45.17", "TR2x45.18", "UT2x45.19", "UT2x45.20", 
"TR2x45.19", "TR2x45.20", "ensayo"), row.names = c("3117", "3118", 
"3119", "3120", "3121", "3122", "3123", "3124", "3125", "3126", 
"3127", "3128", "3129", "3130", "3131", "3132", "15598", "15599", 
"15600", "15601", "15602"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried your code for `summary` and it works.  `by(cs_us[,3:length(cs_us)], cs_us$ensayo, FUN=summary)`  But, the `cs_tiempo` inside the `FUN` seems a bit problematic.  Wouldn't that create a length difference

Comment: Using `by(cs_us[,(3:length(cs_us))-1], cs_us$ensayo, FUN= function(x) desplazar(x$tiempo, x[,-1] ) )` worked without any errors

Comment: Do you want to make it a formal answer? Also, is this going to happen with any helper functions?

Comment: I posted it as solution.  Your desplazar is a custom function.  I don't know if there is a function to replace it.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I ment "will I have to use the "function(x) ..."   with every custom/helper functions?"

Comment: You can drop the `anonymous function call` by making necessary changes in the function or using `Map` i.e. `Map(desplazar, split(cs_us$tiempo, cs_us$ensayo), split(cs_us[3:(ncol(cs_us)-1)], cs_us$ensayo))`

Comment: Updated by modifying the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 by(cs_us[,(3:length(cs_us))-1], cs_us$ensayo, 
           FUN= function(x) desplazar(x$tiempo, x[,-1] ) )
```

Or

```
 Map(desplazar, split(cs_us$tiempo, cs_us$ensayo),
                split(cs_us[3:(ncol(cs_us)-1)], cs_us$ensayo))
```

You can also modify the `desplazar` and remove the anonymous function call in `by`

```
   desplazar1 <- function(data){
     matriz <- as.matrix(data[-1])
     matriz_dif <- abs(diff(matriz))
     matriz_dif_inv <- diffinv(matriz_dif)
     data.frame(tiempo=data['tiempo'], matriz_dif_inv)
    }

    by(cs_us[,(3:length(cs_us))-1], cs_us$ensayo, FUN=desplazar1)
```